# Overloading the delete[] operator for a memory tracker

Tags: c++, oop, memory, memory-management

In order to keep track of memory allocation, I've been trying to overload both the scalar and array versions of the `new` and `delete` operators in C++. However, the overload for `delete[]` doesn't work. I have been trying to understand the documentation on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) but cannot make sense of it. I think I'm interested in the overload # 5, which is the following but might be wrong.

`void operator delete  ( void* ptr, std::size_t sz ) noexcept;`

This is the program that I'm currently testing my idea with along with all the functions that I've written.
Please note that I'm interested in a memory allocator that works with both built-in types and any classes/structs that I create.

```
#include<iostream>

// global variable
std::size_t g_allocatedMemory{};

// =======================================================================
// global overload for new
void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    g_allocatedMemory += size;
    
    std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes\n";
    std::cout << "Current allocation = " << g_allocatedMemory << " bytes\n\n";

    return malloc(size);
}

// global overload for delete
void operator delete(void* memory, std::size_t size)
{
    g_allocatedMemory -= size;

    std::cout << "Freeing " << size << " bytes\n";
    std::cout << "Current allocation = " << g_allocatedMemory << " bytes\n\n";
    
    free(memory);
}

// =======================================================================

// global overload for new[]
void* operator new[](std::size_t size)
{
    g_allocatedMemory += size;
    
    std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes\n";
    std::cout << "Current allocation = " << g_allocatedMemory << " bytes\n\n";

    return malloc(size);
}

// global overload for delete[]
void operator delete[](void* memory, std::size_t size)
{    
    g_allocatedMemory -= size;

    std::cout << "Freeing " ;//<< size << " bytes\n";
    std::cout << "Current allocation = " << g_allocatedMemory << " bytes\n\n";
    
    free(memory);
}

// =======================================================================

int main()
{
    int* p{ new int[5] };

    delete[] p;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried with C++17 as well; it doesn't work.

The program doesn't use the overload that I've provided for `delete[]`. So when I'm `delete[] p` in `main()`, only the output from `int* p{ new int[5] };` is printed on the screen but nothing from `delete[] p;` :

```
Allocating 20 bytes
Current allocation = 20 bytes
```

This is how I'm compiling my code.

`g++ -pedantic-errors -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -std=c++14 .\leak.cpp`

Comment: In `main`, when you call `new[]`, and inside your routine it calls `std::cout`, and let's imagine that `std::cout` needs to make a buffer, so it calls `new[]`, and that routine calls `std::cout`, and let's imagine that `std::cout` needs to make a buffer, so it call `new[]`...

Comment: On my other platform, the `delete[] p;` calls `void operator delete[](void* memory) noexcept`, but you didn't provide that replacement global delete.  That jibes with: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete  — I recommend you replace `malloc` and `free` rather than `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Eljay You can't override `std::malloc` and `std::free`.

Comment: @Eljay There's no guarantee that new, new[], delete, and delete[] use malloc and free for their platform and compiler (and even if it does work, what happens with a different compiler or platform?), so that recommendation is really bad advice.

Comment: @George That's true, but anyway, it is not possible. Even if an implementation do use `std::malloc` and `std::free`, redefining them (override) would violate the one definition rule. (And overloading them would be useless because the new overloads are obviously not the ones that are called).

Comment: @George - All very true.  My comment may or may not be relevant for the OP's problem at hand, and it wasn't clear if portability is a factor.  If the OP's situation is a single platform, and their new/delete and new[]/delete[] are built on top of malloc/free, then intercepting malloc/free would be a good bottleneck to instrument.

Comment: Don't forget about placement new.

Comment: @JesperJuhl placement new doesn't allocate, so doesn't need to be intercepted to monitor allocations

Comment: @Caleth Right. Good point.

Comment: @JesperJuhl although `new(nothrow)` is apparently "a placement version of a new-expression" presumably because that's how the grammar rule is named

Answer (score 2):

You must provide an `operator delete[](void *ptr) noexcept` function.

Note that the [Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/new.delete) requires replacing the non-size version when replacing the version that takes a size.

Simply adding the following code will use the overload:

```cpp
// global overload for delete[]
void operator delete[](void* memory)
{     
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

Your code with this additional overload will output:

```
Allocating 20 bytes
Current allocation = 20 bytes

test
```

Comment: Hi, I am assuming the overload you mention will be the fifth function (excluding `main()` in the program shown above). The problem with this is that I don't print the amount of memory that was deallocated. Also, without the `size` parameter, I am unable to update `g_allocatedMemory`, which means I cannot track the net memory that is currently allocated on the heap by my program.

Also, I am assuming that within the function body of `void operator delete[](void* memory)`, I would need to add the statement, `free(memory)` as well?